# Use Shader output for something other than drawing

Tags: java, parallel-processing, shader, gpu, lwjgl

If I'm not mistaken, shader programs basically run by having operations that can be done in parallel executed by the GPU, which is capable of many operations per second compared to the CPU. I'm wondering if there is any way to use LWJGL to run a shader program and use it for something other than just drawing. For example, if I have one array of arbitrary `float` values, and another `float[]` of equal size, and I want to set each element in the second array equal to -1, 0, or 1, based on the sign of the corresponding element in the first array, it seems to me that there should be some way to have a shader program that looks something like:

```
in float a;

out float b;

void main(void){
    float t = 0;
    if(a > 0)
        t = 1;
    if(a < 0)
        t = -1;
    b = t;
}
```

And run it for each element in the array, passing it the element of the first array as `a` and setting the element of the second array to output `b`. I'd imagine this could be done in much less time for very large arrays if it could be executed on the GPU, and that this would be even more true if more complexity to the operations became necessary. I've tried to use JOCL and CUDA before, but haven't had much luck and found it very complicated, and so far I like what I've seen of what LWJGL's what-appears-to-be-simplicity, so if there is a way to do what I'm asking, please explain. Thank you.

Comment: You could use [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) for this, which is included in LWJGL as well. This allows you to run small programs (similar to shaders) on the GPU (and some other devices). Support for it is not as common as for OpenGL though.